# Impossible Python Script Not Generating Excel File

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping

I've be struggling with this Python script for a few days. I'm trying to scrape data and generate an excel file as an output. I don't get any error messages when I run the code, but the excel file isn't created.

I'm on a Windows 10 os, running script in Sublime Text with the Python Build, I've installed all of the packages in the script, made sure I have permission to write to the CD, but nothing I've tried seems to work. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=y&type=1&season=2023&month=0&season1=2023&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&startdate=2023-01-01&enddate=2023-12-31&page=1_500"

html_content = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

data = {}

leaders = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "rgMasterTable"})
leaders_data = leaders.tbody.find_all("tr")

headings = []

for td in leaders_data[0].find_all("td"):
    if td.b:
        headings.append(td.b.text.replace('\n', '').strip())

for table, heading in zip(leaders_data[1].find_all("table"), headings):
    t_headers = []
    for th in table.find_all("th"):
        t_headers.append(th.text.replace('\n', '').strip())

    table_data = []
    for tr in table.tbody.find_all("tr"):
        t_row = {}
        for td, th in zip(tr.find_all("td"), t_headers):
            t_row[th] = td.text.replace('\n', '').strip()
        table_data.append(t_row)
    data[heading] = table_data

for topic, table in data.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame(table)

    excel_filename = "C:/Users/(myuser)/Documents/rake_list.xlsx"
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
    writer.save()

import os
print(os.path.isfile("rake_list.xlsx")) 
#I've added this to see if it has saved elsewhere but it return "False"
```

I've tried changing the directory, generating a csv file instead of an excel file, running as a command prompt outside of Sublime Text, but the excel file will not generate.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like both `data` and `headings` are empty, so it simply isn't writing a blank file. I think you need to revisit how you're parsing the website to ensure you're properly building your `data` object

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with the filePath. you can try specifying a relative file path instead of an absolute one.
For example, you can use "rake_list.xlsx" as the file name without the full path. This will create the file in the same directory as the Python script.

just Replace this one line of code

```
excel_filename = "rake_list.xlsx"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried both relative and absolute file paths without success.